# PHP Closure - Return an array with key / value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, php-7

I use DomCrawler to grab some data, and I would like to know if I can get an array from a closure, here is my code :

```
    $promises = $products
        ->each(function(Crawler $node) use ($client, $cookieJar) {
            $href = $node->filter('a')->last()->attr('href');

            return [
                $href => $client->getAsync($this->config['url'] . $href, [
                    'cookies' => $cookieJar,
                ])
            ];
        });
```

It will return me like :

```
$promises = [
   ['href_value' => Guzzle\Promise],
   ....
 ];
```

But I would like to have :

```
$promises = [
   'href_value' => Guzzle\Promise,
   ....
 ];
```

How can I tranform the return statetement to have this result, something like this in my mind :

```
return ($href) => $client->getAsync($this->config['url'] . $href, [
        'cookies' => $cookieJar,
    ]);
```

Comment: there's a reason why it's nested, coz it might return more than one, obviously keys must be unique. just reassign it with `reset` or point to index zero

Answer (score 0):

Transform your `$promises` to have flat array:

```php
$flatPromises = [];

foreach ($promises as $promise) {
    foreach ($promise as $key => $value) {
         $flatPromises[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a solution I use now (little different), but I would like to avoid this step if possible